# Unable to update price of an application on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have recently updated my application with a new build. Now I want to change the price of that build.

I did that by :

1.Logging in to my google account

2.Visiting play.google.com/apps/publish

1. Selecting my application
2. Selecting Pricing and Distribution
3. Changing the current price to new one in the default price section
4. Clicked on save and update.

I did this 2 days back and still the price of the application is not updated.

Please suggest me any other steps if I had left out.

Do I need to unpublish the application and then publish it again in order for the Price to get in-effect?

Thanx.

Comment: You are used android inapp services?

Comment: no i haven't used android in-app services. But why do i need it anyway as I am updating the price through the developer/distribution portal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ohk so its resolved. After waiting for 4 more hours, I again followed the same steps and now it was updated within an hour.

It seems that its a server issue from Google End.

Finally, my apps price is updated and available for download.

Thanks for all the upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it turns out, you have to make some other change as well - like add a new space (or something) in the description of the store listing. Only then it will update the price.

Comment: Price not updated even after 9 hours, after this trick price updated within 15 minutes.